# Handling whois connection refused message in shell script

Tags: shell-script

```
blacklist_ips='
    5.56.148.140
    94.73.159.66
    69.134.15.72
    107.150.42.226
    195.159.233.44
    89.19.7.58
'

for ipx in $blacklist_ips
do
    country=`whois $ipx | grep -i country | tail -1 | awk '{print $2}'`
    hostx=`host $ipx |awk '{print $NF}'|sed "s/\.$//"`
    printf '%s %s %s' $country $ipx $hostx          
    printf '\n'
done
```

Script works for all IPs but for `69.134.15.72`,

```
country=`whois $ipx | grep -i country | tail -1 | awk '{print $2}'`
```

results as:

```
connect: Connection refused
```

It is because of

```
whois 69.134.15.72
```

It seems `69.134.15.72` does not respond properly.

I do not understand why it halts at the line of `country` and script execution does not get to next line.

How can I detect the `connection refused` error and react properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by using an if statement and `echo $?` to test the exit status of the last command. The number 0 typically corresponds to a success. Failures can be represented by a range of numbers, depending on the program.

Here, `whois 69.134.15.72; echo $?` produces a 2 because of the `Connection Refused` message.

Running the command for a different IP address that accepts the connection will yield a 0. For instance:

```
$ whois 5.56.148.140 >/dev/null; echo $?
0
```

In that command, I redirected output to /dev/null to avoid clutter. Also, the success or failure of this command from these IP addresses in this post may change in the future.

In your code, you could first test the `whois` command for the particular IP address, then only run the rest of the for statement if the exit status is 0.

Something like:

```
for ipx in $blacklist_ips
do

    whois_test=`whois $ipx 2>/dev/null` 
    ret=$?

    if [ $ret -eq 0 ]; then
        country=`echo "$whois_test" | grep -i country | tail -1 | awk '{print $2}'`
        hostx=`host $ipx |awk '{print $NF}'|sed "s/\.$//"`
        printf '%s %s %s' $country $ipx $hostx          
        printf '\n'
    fi

done
```

The syntax here is as follows:

1. Runs `whois` command on IP address and saves output as variable `whois_test`. stderr will be redirected to /dev/null, producing no additional output on the screen when the command fails.
2. Assigns value of exit status to variable `ret`.
3. If statement checks to see if value of variable `ret` is 0. If so, it continues with the content of your for loop.

The assignment for the variable `country` within the for loop changed slightly. Instead of piping in the output from the `whois` command as originally written, the script now pipes in the value of the `whois_test` variable.

Double quotes are needed to retain formatting in order for `grep` to correctly find the right value for country.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Just a small glitch. "whois $ipx" the one before "ret=$?" prints output. How can I prevent that whois output please?

Comment: I made an edit to include `>/dev/null 2>&1`, which should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you very much again @clk. It works great but it uses 2 whois query. To lessen network attempts, how can we use 1 whois query and still achieve the same result? It would be great if you could share the alternative so that I can learn how to solve it by 1 whois query.

Comment: Ok, I included a second example that should do it with only one `whois` statement. Try it and let me know.

Comment: Thanks again clk. But "ret" does not seem to get a value in second example. Therefore script does not work as expected.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure why. It also looks like when it fails, it includes stderr. I'll remove it for now and add it again if I can get it working with just one call to `whois`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42284/discussion-between-clk-and-necnecco).

Comment: Thanks clk again. By `whois $ipx 2>/dev/null` modification, your second solution works great.